# Definite integral involving Jacobi theta function

Tags: integration, elliptic-functions, theta-functions

Consider an elliptic function $f(z)$, we know how to compute the integral
$$
\int_0^1 f(z)dz,
$$
by expanding $f(z)$ as a sum of $\zeta(z)$ and its derivatives, where the coefficients of the expansion are Laurent coefficients of $f(z)$ at its poles.

**Question: is there a similar trick to compute**
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{ \vartheta_4'(z, \tau) }{ \vartheta_4(z, \tau) }f(z)dz ?
$$
The $\vartheta_4$ factor slightly breaks the ellipticity
$$
\frac{ \vartheta'_4(z + \tau|\tau) }{ \vartheta_4(z + \tau |\tau) } = \frac{ \vartheta'_4(z|\tau) }{ \vartheta_4(z|\tau) } + 2\pi i \ .
$$

Comment: I think you meant "$\wp$ and its derivaties".

Comment: @Somos actually $\zeta$ is needed to build elliptic functions with multiple simple poles (with canceling residues of course)